# What is the purpose of defining the notion of inflection point?

Tags: calculus, terminology, graphing-functions, math-history

What is the purpose of defining inflection point?

I know that it is defined to be the point where the second derivative is zero and the second derivative sign changes.

It has to have some purpose for pure math.

Comment: To analyze them.

Comment: It can be of importance in various ways. For example, if our displacement (position) at time $t$ is given by $s(t)$, the inflection points of $s(t)$ are the places where our acceleration changes from positive to negative, or vice-versa.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - I mean the purpose in pure math not physics

Comment: For instance, when there were no beautiful online graphing calculators, it helped drawing graphs properly. Note also that it generalizes to the notion of saddle point in higher dimension: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point This is an important notion in dynamical systems.

Comment: Mathematical physics is hard to separate from mathematics. Here is another example. When we are approximating a function by a secant line (a line joining two points on the curve) it is often useful to know whether we have an overestimate (convex curve, usually called concave up in calculus courses) or an underestimate. Similar considerations apply for approximation by a tangent line.

Comment: I don't know if this counts as a pure math application, but I posted some subtle real analysis issues connected with the notion "inflection point" in [this 24 December 2005 AP-calculus post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4160939) at Math Forum. In particular, in this post I summarized Andrew M. Bruckner's paper *Some nonequivalent definitions of inflection points*, American Mathematical Monthly 69 #8 (October 1962), 787-789.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Inflection point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point) is more than just the second derivative being zero as one could take $f(x)=x^4$ which would have the second derivative be zero at $x=0$ yet it isn't an inflection point as the second derivative doesn't change sign.  Have you ever looked at a graph of a tangent through an inflection point?  $g(x)=x^3$ at $x=0$ would be an example where it is worth noting that the tangent goes through the curve here.

Wikipedia defines it this way:

> In differential calculus, an inflection point, point of inflection,
>   flex, or inflection (inflexion) is a point on a curve at which the
>   curvature or concavity changes sign from plus to minus or from minus
>   to plus. The curve changes from being concave upwards (positive
>   curvature) to concave downwards (negative curvature), or vice versa.

I'd imagine this could be useful for considering optimization problems to know if a curve is concave one way or another.